# Omnisharp 1.9.0 extension for VSCode not recognize CSProj file for DotNet Core

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

When I try to open a dotNet core 1.1 mvc project in visual studio code, the csproj file is not recognized and I cant get any symbols from the project.

VSCode displays a [warn] message saying *"Some projects have trouble loading, please review the output for more details"*. In the output i got the following message:

> [warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem
>           Failed to process project file 'c:\Users\humam\Projects\AM\AM.csproj'.
>   c:\Users\humam\Projects\AM\AM.csproj(1,1)
>   Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The imported
>   project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web\Sdk\Sdk.props"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk. 
>   c:\Users\humam\Projects\AM\AM.csproj    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject(String
>   errorSubCategoryResourceName, IElementLocation elementLocation, String
>   resourceName, Object[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject(IElementLocation
>   elementLocation, String resourceName, Object arg0)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpression(String
>   directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, String
>   unescapedExpression, Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError, List`1&
>   imports)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImports(String
>   directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String
>   directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement
>   currentProjectOrImport)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Reevaluate(ILoggingService
>   loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary(ILoggingService
>   loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Initialize(IDictionary`2
>   globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion,
>   ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor(String projectFile,
>   IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String
>   subToolsetVersion, ProjectCollection projectCollection,
>   ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject(String
>   fileName, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion)    at
>   OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Create(String
>   projectFilePath, String solutionDirectory, ILogger logger,
>   MSBuildOptions options, ICollection`1 diagnostics, Boolean
>   isUnityProject)    at
>   OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem.CreateProjectFileInfo(String
>   projectFilePath, Boolean isUnityProject)

Any idea what could be the source of this problem?

My environment is Windows 10 includes DotNet Core SDK 1.1.0, VSCode 1.12.2 and Omnisharp 1.9.0 C# extension for VSCode along with other extensions.

The project is created using dotnet core command "dotnet new mvc --auth Individual -o AM".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OmniSharp seems to load the VS 2017 build tools which don't support .NET Core projects at the moment: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1697. Try installing a version of VS 2017 with the web development / cross-platform workloads instead or create an `omnisharp.json` file in your project containing:

```
{
    "msbuild": {
        "msbuildextensionspath": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\1.0.4\\Sdks"
    }
}
```

You then need to `dotnet restore` via command line (since the build tools also don't contain a version of NuGet) and reload the project in VSCode.

Comment: What should Mac users be doing about this issue?

Comment: You could use the path to your sdk folder but discovery works differently on macOS so your issue is probably something different (problem here was different visual studio installs).

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this same problem in making a .NET core 3 project here is what worked for me.

my omnisharp.json file :

```
{
    "MSBuild": {
        "UseLegacySdkResolver": true
    }
 }
```

and my global.json (optional, check your sdk version by "dotnet --list-sdks")

```
{
    "sdk": {
      "version": "3.0.100"
    }
}
```

source: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/3287#issuecomment-536180721

Comment: This solved my issue with OmniSharp and both VS2017 and VS2019 installed plus dotnet core SDK 3.1